# My Docker container does not have IP address. Why?

Tags: docker

I started a `rethinkDB` docker container using the command

```
docker pull rethinkdb:2.3
docker run --rm --name rethinkdb -v /srv/rethinkdb:/data --net host rethinkdb:2.3 rethinkdb --bind all --cache-size 8192 --no-update-check
```

Now the container started successfully. I did `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
f288961ef376        rethinkdb:2.3       "rethinkdb --bind ..."   9 minutes ago       Up 9 minutes                            rethinkdb
1f71722698ae        sorccu/adb:latest   "/sbin/tini -- adb..."   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes                           adbd
```

Now I want to find out the IP address of this container. So I did

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' f288961ef376
```

It's returning me nothing. I couldn't find IP address for this container.

I checked if the `rethinkDB` configuration page is up or not by going to `http://localhost:8080` and I see it's up and running.

Why doesn't this container have any IP address?

Output of `docker inspect` is as follows

```
[
    {
        "Id": "f288961ef376531c97d2264cb8ef3c6077a6a75107905d6a47734303adfcb117",
        "Created": "2017-05-05T11:13:45.382460184Z",
        "Path": "rethinkdb",
        "Args": [
            "--bind",
            "all",
            "--cache-size",
            "8192",
            "--no-update-check"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 8157,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-05-05T11:13:45.774035358Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:c5ed876750b40cde4725ea9eb9d8503f4d1419a2f23ac2ef8e4cc1d535e2c3a2",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f288961ef376531c97d2264cb8ef3c6077a6a75107905d6a47734303adfcb117/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f288961ef376531c97d2264cb8ef3c6077a6a75107905d6a47734303adfcb117/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f288961ef376531c97d2264cb8ef3c6077a6a75107905d6a47734303adfcb117/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/f288961ef376531c97d2264cb8ef3c6077a6a75107905d6a47734303adfcb117/f288961ef376531c97d2264cb8ef3c6077a6a75107905d6a47734303adfcb117-json.log",
        "Name": "/rethinkdb",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "docker-default",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/srv/rethinkdb:/data"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": true,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": null,
            "Name": "aufs"
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "/srv/rethinkdb",
                "Destination": "/data",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "dev-machine",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "28015/tcp": {},
                "29015/tcp": {},
                "8080/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "RETHINKDB_PACKAGE_VERSION=2.3.5~0jessie"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "rethinkdb",
                "--bind",
                "all",
                "--cache-size",
                "8192",
                "--no-update-check"
            ],
            "Image": "rethinkdb:2.3",
            "Volumes": {
                "/data": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "/data",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "bd17bf8e1663ff18f6674a1a3a1665c4e1bf65283d358ffc97dc238ef4a79088",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "30b6150968580d33aae0e45f7d850b9e67ae2aa29e1bb837ca4fa74f2b0d4d42",
                    "EndpointID": "05e93ec514ee6694e57d344f3e4362252104347c3cc48c607708d125715ed6ec",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: try without format option

Comment: @bxN5 : I even inspected the `JSON` output of `docker inspect f288961ef376` manually. I don't see the IP address

Comment: attach pls output of inspect without format option

Comment: @bxN5 : done. pls see the original post

Comment: it's kind of guessing but try to add ti startp -p and set port and –net=host

Comment: Didn't help. I tried that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your container ip the the same as the host. `host` basically says that your container uses the same network interface as the host. It is fast since there's no bridging but limited; You have to make sure that your containers do not listen to the same port to avoid conflicts.

It's better to stick with the default `bridge` network and specify the port that you want exposed to the host. For instance:

```
docker run --rm --name rethinkdb -v /srv/rethinkdb:/data -p 8080:8080 \
    rethinkdb:2.3 rethinkdb --bind all --cache-size 8192 --no-update-check
```

btw, `--net` has been renamed `--network` in later versions of Docker.

Answer (score 34):

You are starting your container with the `--net host` option which means your container will run on your host network. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316376/what-does-net-host-option-in-docker-command-really-do/43317607#43317607) for more info. So your container will be accessible on the IP of your host.

A very basic example:

```
$ docker run --net=host -d jenkins
```

This will run jenkins on your real host network. So when you open the firewall (jenkins runs on 8080) you will access your container immediatly.
So I open the firewall:

```
$ sudo iptables -I INPUT 5 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

I check the real IP of my eth0 (host network) with `ifconfig`. (I'm doing this on a VM). It is inet `192.168.140.7`. I go in my browser to 192.168.140.7:8080 and I see the jenkins. So your container has no own IP. It's running on your host network and host IP.

If you leave the `--net host` option, the container will be created in the default docker bridge network with range `"172.17.0.0/16"`. Now your container will get an IP from in the range of that network. To access the container from the outside you have to map your ports on your host network (see the more info). You can do this with the `-p` option.

So for the jenkins example:

```
$ docker run -d -p 8888:8080 jenkins
```

When I perform a `docker inspect` I see:

```
"IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
```

So my container is running in the bridge network on 172.17.0.4:8080.
Now with the `-p` option I'm mapping the port 8080 of my bridge network on 8888 of my host network: so `host-IP:8888`. Now it's accessible from the outside.

Comment: This answer is good but in my case I wasn't using any --net option!

Comment: How can I ping/ssh to a docker that runs like that?

Comment: docker assigns a local IP which is only accessible through the host itselft. if you want to ping you have to use a port to host and ping that port

Answer (score 2):

I've remarked that stopped docker containers don't have any IP assigned to them when you do "docker inspect", so you gotta be sure that it's running.

Ofc if your network is the host so: --net host, there won't be any IP address assigned to the container.