# Identify Docker container's IP Address and connect to port

Tags: docker

On my `windows` laptop I have created a `Play` application which runs fine if I execute its scripts directly. On the local machine, I access the application using `localhost:9000` URL.

I have now created a `Docker` image of the application and have exposed port `9000`

```
#this docker file copies prod specific files to container, eg logback_prod.xml and application_prod.conf

    FROM openjdk:8
    #ENV APP_NAME      myapp
    #ENV APP_VERSION   1.0-SNAPSHOT
...
    #entrypoint is deploy/....
    EXPOSE 9000
    ENTRYPOINT ...
```

But I can't access the application on `localhost:9000`. I suspect that the image might be running on some other IP created by docker itself.

Am I correct? How can I access my application through the container? I don't need `Kubernetes` `Services` etc. as I already have that setup on another machine. My specific question is how to access the `docker` container directly.

UPDATE
I also tried running the `docker` `image` using `--network="host"` but that doesn't work either

UPDATE 2

Based on the suggestions below, I executed the following commands but still can't access the application.

`docker run -p 9000:9000 --env-file env.txt imagename`

I see the trace

```
[debug] a.i.TcpListener - Successfully bound to /0.0.0.0:9000
[info] p.c.s.AkkaHttpServer - Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000
```

`docker ps -a` shows application is up with port binding `0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp`

`docker inspect` shows `IP` - `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"`

but `http://172.17.0.2:9000/` on `Chrome` doesn't work `This site can’t be reached172.17.0.2`

`netstat -ab` on `cmd` shows `TCP    0.0.0.0:9000           LAPTOP-788I0GL1:0      LISTENING [com.docker.backend.exe]`

Comment: How did you start the container?  You should be able to connect to a `docker run -p` port number; just `EXPOSE` in a Dockerfile isn't enough.  The container-private IP address is an internal Docker implementation detail that doesn't work in many common situations (from a different host, if Docker is in a VM, on MacOS or Windows platforms) and I would not recommend looking it up.

Comment: Most recently, I did `docker run -p 9000:9000 --env-file env.txt manuchadha25/mydockerimage`. I can see `0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp` when I do `docker ps -a`

Comment: Does the application listen on 127.0.0.1:9000 ("localhost only"), 0.0.0.0:9000 ("all interfaces"), or something else?  (It should be the 0.0.0.0 variant, and the port number needs to match the second `-p` port.)  Are you using Docker Toolbox?  (That needs a special `docker-machine ip` address, perhaps 192.168.99.100, instead of `localhost`.)

Comment: `Listening for HTTP on /0.0.0.0:9000`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### *Identify container's IP Address*

*Try these options with a running container.
`<docker>` refers to container's name or id*

```
docker inspect --format '{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}' <docker>

//WINDOWS ONLY
docker inspect --format "{{ .NetworkSettings.IPAddress }}" <docker>
```

---

```
docker inspect <docker> | grep "IPAddress"
```

*Grep not avaliable on Windows**

---

```
docker network inspect bridge
```

This last one would output all running containers' info that are allocated in the **`bridge`** network *(default)*. Once identified, check the container's *`IPv4Address`* field.

---

### ***Expose ports***

In order to be able to connect to the a container's port, you could expose it. *Note that the previous step is not needed in this case:*

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 --env-file env.txt manuchadha25/mydockerimage
```

By default the docker will *bind/listen* to all interfaces on the host. The  `-p 9000:9000` option exposes the port, and as a result you get: *`0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp`*

Now **`localhost:9000`** succesfully connects to your docker process.

Comment: Thanks. Did that but it doesn't show anything. Just an empty output

Comment: I see "IPAddress": "".when I run `inspect`. Is this weird? Also, I am on Windows so no `Grep` for me

Comment: sorry, the mistake earlier was I was running using `--network="host"`. I removed that and did only `docker run`. I can now see IP `"IPAddress": "172.17.0.2"` but I can't still access the app using `172.17.0.2:9000`

Comment: that's because you must "expose" the port to the host when running the container. try the syntax docker run (...) -p 9200:9200 (...) ---> https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-expose-port-on-running-container/3252/8

Comment: did `docker run -p 9000:9000 --env-file env.txt manuchadha25/mydockerimage` but no love. I am sure it is some silly mistake somewhere as this isn't suppose to be difficult. I can see `0.0.0.0:9000->9000/tcp` when I do `docker ps -a`

Comment: `0.0.0.0:9000->9000` should let you make a `localhost:9000` call

Comment: I have no clue what just happened but now I can access `localhost:9000`!

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is binded to all interfaces, and since the port is exposed, localhost:9000 is a valid endpoint. Glad you could fix it!

Answer (score 2):

You can try the command `docker inspect`:

```
docker inspect <containerid>
```

for list the containers ids you can run the command:

```
docker ps
```

In order to get the ipAddress information you should look to node:

```
"IPAddress": "172.23.0.2"
```

In the json output produced.

Here is the documentation for [docker inspect command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/).

Comment: I see "IPAddress": "".when I run `inspect`. Is this weird?

Comment: Found that question with accepted answer, maybe that's your case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803849/my-docker-container-does-not-have-ip-address-why

Comment: Thanks. Will check. Sorry, the mistake earlier was I was running using --network="host". I removed that and did only docker run. I can now see IP "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2" but I can't still access the app using 172.17.0.2:9000