# Is docker run --net=host analogous to the "Host" network mode on AWS ECS?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

Was following discussions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316376/what-does-net-host-option-in-docker-command-really-do) article. We want to bring up our Dockerized application in ECS and currently the application run as a standalone docker container using the command

```
docker run --net=host -d -p PORT:PORT My-APP
```

The question is - if we migrate to ECS - does this `--net-host` setting Map to the `Host` Networking Mode in ECS?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Yes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#network_mode):

> If the network mode is `host`, the task bypasses Docker's built-in virtual network and maps container ports directly to the EC2 instance's network interface directly. In this mode, you can't run multiple instantiations of the same task on a single container instance when port mappings are used.