# AWS Lambda Connecting to Local Postgres in Docker

Tags: aws-lambda

I'm attempting to connect to a local Postgres server running as a docker container from my Lambda function.

I'm using the `sam local invoke` call to do so.

For some reason, it seems that outgoing connection from SAM's docker container for the function is disabled.

I'm getting this error message:

```
"errorMessage": "(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused\n\tIs the server running on host \"localhost\" (127.0.0.1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\ncould not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address\n\tIs the server running on host \"localhost\" (::1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\n\n(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)",
```

Is there a way to enable a Lambda function call to a **local** docker database?

*I have no issues running the connection code outside the Lambda function as standard Python code - so I'm sure my database is up, my code works, etc.*

Answer (score 2):

Try running the command with `—docker-network TEXT` per the AWS SAM CLI [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-invoke.html).

I had a similar issue attempting to run `sam local start-api` with a local Docker Postgres database and was getting `connection refused` errors. I ran `sam local start-api —docker-network host` and it resolved the issue.

This is a good post which helped me to understand more about [Docker networks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43316376/what-does-net-host-option-in-docker-command-really-do).

Hope this helps you and any others looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this by replacing localhost with host.docker.internal.

For example if you use psycopg2

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="host.docker.internal",port=5432, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was banging my head against the wall with this